# Install Google Script installable trigger .onFormSubmit from another script ran by .onFormSubmit

Tags: javascript, forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have the following setup:
The form, attached to the master sheet, upon submission runs the script that creates a new spreadsheet (copies from the template) and a new form (which is generated from scratch on the fly).
Then it connects the new form to the new spreadsheet as a submission destination.
After that I do some modifications to that new spreadsheet and trying to install a trigger by running:

```
function setTrigger() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(NEW_SHEET_ID);
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
 .forSpreadsheet(sheet)
 .onFormSubmit()
 .create();
}
```

The function reports complete success in the logs.

BUT when I look into the script editor of the new spreadsheet, to "Current project's triggers" I see nothing in there.

When I look into "All your triggers", I can see that myFunction is set to run .onFormSubmit, but obviously I can't understand which script/sheet it is attached to.

If I try to submit the new form, it gets submitted to the new sheet, but no .onFormSubmit events get triggered.

I tried running the same trigger-set function by hand from stand alone script, but SAME RESULT.

I'm at a loss. Am I missing something? Or it is a bug?

Comment: Can you post your myFunction that is suppose to run when a form is submitted to the other sheet? I ask because maybe it is accessing the wrong sheet to run its function?

Comment: @JackBrown, "myFunction" is only dealing with copying and reformatting data from the form submission to the other sheet within the same spreadsheet, so that isn't a problem. I tried running it with just `Logger.log` and it still wouldn't get triggered.

Comment: Hmm.. any way to answer part of your question. The new spreadsheet has no trigger under current projects because no projects in that script editor was used to create a trigger. The trigger that was setup will be run by a different script on a different spreadsheet I.e. different project. So it is a normal behaviour.

Comment: So in essence, if you have multiple form all will(or should) trigger same "myfunction" when form is submitted on any of them. You can try to setup onFromSubmit() forForm with your new created form, could be a alternative solution that might work.

Comment: @Jack, Here is the quote from the documentation "For example, a standalone script can programmatically create an installable trigger for an arbitrary Google Sheets file by calling TriggerBuilder.forSpreadsheet(key) and passing in the spreadsheet's ID." Perhaps I understand it wrong, but I don't see how the question above can be "normal behaviour". I tried doing it for the newly created form to no avail. It seems it might have something to do with permissions and the processes that create the files and triggers.

Comment: When I say normal behavior I refer to the fact that you cannot see the newly created trigger under current project trigger of the newly create spreadsheet. You will the find the newly created trigger under current project trigger of the spreadsheet that created the trigger. Hope that clarifies what I was trying to say.